# Remove duplicates in the pandas dataframe with respect to columns in python using dynamic columns list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, duplicates

Here i have a dataframe which looks like this

```
   X1  X2   X3
0   1   1   1
1   1   2   2
2   1   3   3
3   2   1   2
4   2   2   2
5   2   3   3
6   3   1   1
```

I want the output as below

```
   X1  X2   X3
1   1   2   2
2   1   3   3
3   2   1   2
5   2   3   3
6   3   1   1
```

Help me to find the easiest way to remove same values from dataframe

Comment: I don't have 1,1 multiple times, in the dataframe,

Comment: I want to remove common values in both columns, I don't want 1,1, or 2,2, or 3,3 in my output

Comment: Sorry, wrong duplicate, check the updated link